# docker-compose gives ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've cloned a docker setup which uses docker-compose. One remote developer confirms it works so my problem seems to be with my setup.

I ran `docker-compose up`, but that currently gives me this:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating volume "mycompanydocker_mysql-data" with local driver
Creating volume "mycompanydocker_redis-data" with local driver
Creating volume "mycompanydocker_app-data" with local driver
Creating volume "mycompanydocker_mongo-data" with local driver
mycompanydocker_redis_1 is up-to-date
mycompanydocker_mongo_1 is up-to-date
mycompanydocker_mysql_1 is up-to-date
Building app
ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysql:
    build: mysql/.
    env_file: env
    expose:
    - 3306
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
    - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  mongo:
    build: mongo/.
    env_file: env
    expose:
    - 27017
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
    - mongo-data:/data/db

  redis:
    build: redis/.
    env_file: env
    expose:
    - 6379
    ports:
    - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
    - redis-data:/data

  app:
    build: app/.
    env_file: env
    expose:
     - 80
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    volumes:
    # To mount a local directory, change this
    # To use a docker volume
    - app-data:/app
    # local app
    # - ./mycompany:/app
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    - mongo
    - redis

volumes:
  app-data:
    driver: local
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
  redis-data:
    driver: local
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

and the tree looks like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── README.rst
├── app
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── setup.sh
│   │   ├── start-nginx.sh
│   │   ├── start-rqworker.sh
│   │   ├── start.sh
│   │   └── update.sh
│   ├── etc
│   │   ├── nginx
│   │   │   └── sites-available
│   │   │       └── app
│   │   ├── supervisor
│   │   │   └── conf.d
│   │   │       └── supervisord.conf
│   │   └── supervisord.conf
│   └── ssh
│       └── id_rsa
├── docker-compose.yml
├── env
├── mongo
│   └── Dockerfile
├── mysql
│   └── Dockerfile
└── redis
    └── Dockerfile
```

The thing I don't understand is that `docker-compose` seems to find all `Dockerfile`s, except for the one in the `app` folder. I've got the following installed on OSX 10.11.2:

- `Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd`
- `docker-compose version 1.6.2, build 4d72027`

I'm just starting out with Docker and I'm kinda stuck here. Does anybody know what could possibly be wrong or how I can debug this? All tips are welcome!

**[EDIT]**
I forgot to mention that there is no hidden `.dockerignore` file:

```
$ ls -la
total 56
drwx------@   11 kramer  staff    374 25 mrt 14:13 .
drwx------+ 1134 kramer  staff  38556 26 mrt 17:27 ..
-rw-r--r--@    1 kramer  staff   8196 26 mrt 08:14 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--@    1 kramer  staff     23 24 mrt 15:29 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--@    1 kramer  staff   3879 24 mrt 15:29 README.rst
drwxr-xr-x@    7 kramer  staff    238 25 mrt 14:26 app
-rw-r--r--@    1 kramer  staff    868 25 mrt 17:50 docker-compose.yml
-rw-r--r--@    1 kramer  staff    219 24 mrt 15:29 env
drwxr-xr-x@    3 kramer  staff    102 24 mrt 15:29 mongo
drwxr-xr-x@    3 kramer  staff    102 24 mrt 15:29 mysql
drwxr-xr-x@    3 kramer  staff    102 24 mrt 15:29 redis
```

and the `.gitignore` file doesn't contain anything special either (don't know if it matters):

```
$ cat .gitignore
.project
.pydevproject
```

Comment: Check if you have a hidden `.dockerignore` file which may contain `Dockerfile` in its content. Another possible reason is that you have symlinks in your folder structure.

Comment: @warmoverflow - I forgot to mention that there is no `.dockerignore`. I searched the whole file system (`sudo find / -name .dockerignore`) and did find one `.dockerignore` file, but that was in some totally unrelated repo. Also, there are no symlinks in the project.

Comment: Can you explicitly specify the Dockerfile name to see if it works. see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#context. `build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate`

Comment: @warmoverflow - I tried explicitly specifying the docker file, but I get an `Unsupported config option for services.app: 'dockerfile'`. According to [this issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/85) specifying a dockerfile is not supported. Any other ideas?

Comment: For me, the issue was that my Dockerfiles were specified in a directory. The `dockerfile` is relative to the supplied `context` for the build.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Here is how to specify dockerfile. Sorry I cannot do it in comments as formatting is not supported over there.

**The dockerfile is searched into the defined build context**, that is, you don't specify any path, just the filename of your Dockerfile.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#context

```
app:
    build:
      context: app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I just found the issue. Turns out the name of the Dockerfile was `Dockerfile `, including a space at the end. I have no idea how that space got there, but yeah, it's working again.. :-)  Thanks a million for your suggestions though! I'll accept your answer, because it would have also led me to the solution.

Comment: Glad you found out. This is very hard to notice.

Comment: For those who are not clear on why this works, the reason is because the `dockerfile` is searched for WITHIN the defined build context.

Comment: Thanks, this is the simplest way to run docker on Visual Studio 2017, save my time alot!! I tried to try to solve this issue more than 2 days now. Dont know why the template dont make list this answer as a default template

Answer (score 18):

I had this problem on Windows with a `docker-compose.yml` created by a Visual Studio template. The template was created as:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: <ProjectFolder>\Dockerfile
```

And I was getting error: `Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: <ProjectFolder>\Dockerfile`. I changed the `\` to `/` and it started working for me (i.e. `<ProjectFolder>/Dockerfile`). Maybe that will help if anyone has this error on Windows.

Comment: also, fwiw, it is looking for the Dockerfile relative to the context specified. So my `context: ./services/export/` needed `dockerfile: config/Dockerfile` where config was a folder inside export.

Comment: @Evan Morrison
Thanks for the sample, my docker files where in a folder named Docker, so I had to write the path inside the ymal file like: dockerfile: ./docker/docker-apache.dockerfile

Answer (score 6):

Inside the `docker-compose.yml` file to do the change, in order to meet the Dockerfile:

```
app:
  build: ./app
```

Answer (score 4):

Tried several variations, for some unknown reason I had to use an absolute path for it to work

```
├── visit-count
|   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── files
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── package.json

version: '3.5'
services:
  visit-count:
    build: 
      context: /Users/deltapeng/source/repos/visit-count/files/
      dockerfile: /Users/deltapeng/source/repos/visit-count/Dockerfile
```

But after I got above working, found that this relative path worked too.

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  visit-count:
    build: 
      context: ./files/
      dockerfile: ../
```

Answer (score 4):

wrong path,
my shortest way on linux ubuntu when dockerfile and compose in same location

```
build: ./
```

Comment: Good catch! I had the same situation

Comment: I'd followed the Docker tutorial on using python/Flask and then restructured my files to follow the structure that seemed to be used elsewhere for Flask and hadn't changed this or the location of my Dockerfile.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the docker file name properly and it is case sensitive. I had uppercase letter in DockerFile and so it cannot find them. Hope it helps someone, who struggled like me. Better to use the dockerfile attribute in docker compose file.

```
app:
    build:
      dockerfile: DockerFile
```

Answer (score 2):

Is `path` where you expect the Dockerfile? You can check using the `--verbose` flag like:

```
docker-compose --verbose up | grep compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable | grep path
```

for example:

```
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build <- 
(pull=False, cache_from=None, stream=True, nocache=False, labels=None,
tag='your_app',
buildargs={'some_build': '1901', 'addr': '0.0.0.0', 'corsdomain': '*',
'rpcport': '8545'}, forcerm=False, rm=True,

path='/Users/jmunsch/Desktop/dev/your_app/app?', # in the verbose output

dockerfile='Dockerfile')
```

in Dockerfile define the ARGS:

```
ARG some_flag=
ARG some_build=1900
ARG addr=0.0.0.0
ARG corsdomain="*"
ARG rpcport=8545
```

and in a compose file like :

```
build:
    context: ./your_app
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    args:
      some_flag:       # --some_flag
      some_build: 1901 # --some_build 1901
      rpcaddr: 0.0.0.0 # --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0
      rpcport: 8545    # --rpcport 8545
      corsdomain: "*"  # --corsdomain
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was wrong branch on git. Don't forget to set the specific branch if you build your image from remote context. Url for context should looks like this:

```
services:                                                                                                                                                                                                 
wss-home:                                                                                                                                                                                               
  build:                                                                                                                                                                                                
  context: "http://${LOGIN}:${PASSWD}@host/path/to/repository.git#branch_name"                                                                                                        
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
```

Comment: This was also my mistake 

Comment: I forgot to clone the submodules :)

Comment: @nathanfranke thanks for the comment. It is worth a separate answer to be honest.

Comment: My solution wasn't really an answer, because it is out of the scope of this issue. The only answer would be I guess "Make sure it exists"

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem with Visual Studio's automatically created docker-compose file and tried @crgolden solution but it didn't work.

I only get it to run after:

```
1) Renaming the file VS created from DockerFile to Dockerfile (notice the lower case 'f')
2) change the config to this:
services:
    ...
    <image-name>:
         build:
             context: <project_name>
             dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  build: 
          context: ./
          dockerfile: DockerFile
```

this might help for version:'3.8'
for the current directory set up 
otherwise, have to specify  dockerfile absolute path like

```
build: 
          context: .
          dockerfile: <project_directory>\DockerFile
```

Comment: In my case, the relative path for  param `dockerfile` has to use `/`, instead of `\\`, which blocked me a day.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error because I had my docker-compose in a child directory. What I didn't realize is that in a docker-compose file:

- The build context you specify is relative to where the docker-compose file is located (in the correct first screenshot, the build context moves up two directories from the docker compose file location and is at the base of the repository)
- The dockerfile location you specify is relative to where the build context is set (in the correct first screenshot, I need to go down two directories, into service/deploy, to find the Dockerfile because I just set the context two directories up)

[image]

What I was doing before which was resulting in the error: "Cannot locate specified Dockerfile":

[image]

I hope this helps someone out!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turns out that the docker-compose version is too old, `1.25.0`, I update the `docker-compose` to `v2.13.0`, like below

```
sudo apt-get remove docker-compose
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.13.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
docker-compose -v
```

afterwards, the `context: .` is okay.

Answer (score -1):

I had faced the same issue on ubuntu vm.
I did the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker-compose
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

I hope this will resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

build: 
context: ./   
dockerfile: DockerFile

just add

build: 
context: ./   
dockerfile: DockerFile.dockerfile