# Windows: docker-compose cannot locate the specified Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

On Windows, the following `docker-compose` file is failing to build containers with the error `ERROR: Cannot locate the specified Dockerfile: containers\local\django\Dockerfile`:

```
version: "3"

services:

  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: containers/local/django/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: ["/wait-for-it.sh", "postgres:5432", "--", "/start.sh"]
```

This is just an excerpt, there are a couple more services defined in the actual file.  The strange part is, the same `docker-compose` file working just fine on my development box (Fedora 28).  It seemed to randomly break one day, to my knowledge not related to a system update or an update to Docker for Windows.

The Dockerfiles specified in the compose file definitely exist, at those paths.  Is this a known issue, are there any workarounds?  Could it be a Windows host to Linux container path translation issue?

*Update*: I've temporarily worked around this by reverting to `docker-compose` version 1.19.  That's not a long term fix, but it may help narrow down the cause of the problem.

Comment: Can you confirm that `containers/local/django/Dockerfile` is indeed correct relative to your `docker-compose` file? Can you try `./containers/local/django/Dockerfile` and see if that solves the problem?

Comment: Confirmed, output of `ls` on the Fedora workstation below (I don't have access to the Windows box right now, but it's literally the same git repository at the same commit), with `ls -lh containers/local/django/Dockerfile` outputting `-rw-r--r--. 1 brett brett 1013 Jun 11 09:18 containers/local/django/Dockerfile`.

I've tried both dot-prefixed (`./containers/...`) and plain (`containers/...`) on the Windows machine, and both fail with the same "Cannot locate the specified Dockerfile" error.  I've also tried resetting Docker for Windows.

Comment: I've also tried backslash-delimited paths (`containers\\local\\django\\Dockerfile`) as well as without escaping those backslashes in case the YAML parser is behaving unusually.  Same result in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I found it here:
[docker-compose gives ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236491/docker-compose-gives-error-cannot-locate-specified-dockerfile-dockerfile)

Instead of folder/Dockerfile

```
logstash:  
    #build: Logstash/Dockerfile
    build:
      context: Logstash
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

It works!