# Dockerfile error during creating a Django project with Docker

Tags: django, docker

I try to start a django/postgresql project with Docker. I have 3 files in the project folder (Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, requirements.txt)

When I run:

```
sudo docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample .
```

I get the following error:

```
Starting backend_db_1 ... done
Building web
ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

requirements.txt

```
Django>=2.0,<3.0
psycopg2>=2.7,<3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Give out `tree` command output may be helpful.

Maybe you should look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236491/docker-compose-gives-error-cannot-locate-specified-dockerfile-dockerfile).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it's my stupid typo mistake. OK many people may have this simple problem because we're all used to write words with camel case, so let me write as the answer. It's Dockerfile, not DockerFile:

```
mv DockerFile Dockerfile
```